# TimeZone or DST issue in Win7 or IE9?

Tags: windows, internet-explorer-9, time-zone

Does anyone know about an issue with Windows 7, IE9 and time zones and/or DST (Daylight Time Savings)?

I ask, because when we calculate and print the beginning of each month (with javascript) one of our workstations prints the following lines:

```
2011-10-01 00:00:00 UTC+2
2011-11-01 00:00:00 UTC+2
2011-12-01 00:00:00 UTC+1
```

but here in Austria, we switch to winter time in october, so on all other workstations it looks like this...

```
2011-10-01 00:00:00 UTC+2
2011-11-01 00:00:00 UTC+1
2011-12-01 00:00:00 UTC+1
```

...which is correct.

I already checked many settings of the workstation. Date, Time, Timezone,... everything's configured properly. Any idea?

Comment: There was a DST patch released a week or so ago, do a manual windows update on the PC.

Comment: Are you sure there isn't a bug in your code?  If the settings on all your workstations are the same, that would be my first guess, debug the javascript.  The fact only a single workstation does this ( I doubt you have 1 Windows 7 workstation ) also means there is something different about that workstation.

Comment: Ughh, Time zones. Yet another strange factor you have to take into when writing an OS.  Not disk performance. Not UI design. Not Productivity concerns. But Time Zones.

Answer (score 0):

.

[There was a DST patch released in August](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/2570791), do a manual windows update on the PC.

.

Comment: by the way, this patch was already installed on the pc